# Allow moderators to edit/delete comments directly from the per-user comment moderation page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, moderator-tools

A while back, a new dashboard was added to the user moderation tools to [allow moderators to view all of a user's comments directly from their profile](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121408/show-moderators-a-users-deleted-comments-in-their-profile).

It's great for scouring a user's comment history to find certain comments, but I can't do anything from this dashboard except filter by flagged<sup>1</sup>, deleted, or active comments, and visit the posts to which the comments are attached where I can then edit or delete them.

Can we have the ability to edit and delete comments from this dashboard just as we're able to from the flag queue? It gets particularly tedious to have to open 100 tabs just to delete 100 spam comments from the posts they're attached to (and no, I'm not making that number up<sup>2</sup>...).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>[As of mid-2016](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243715/allow-moderators-to-see-a-summary-of-flags-against-a-users-comments/280681#280681).</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Alright, fine, I made that up; the actual number of spam comments I had to delete was **111**.</sub>

Comment: Give us a delete all the things button already!

Comment: To play devils advocate, I think it's better to be forced to go and look at the comment thread so that you understand the context of a comment before deleting, and to mop up other comments that may depend on the one you just deleted. Either that or the dev team could show us the whole comment thread in a twisty thing.

Comment: I vote for the twisty thing. Twisty is good.

Comment: Either way, the system could use a bit of consistency in this regard.

Comment: For deletion there's this userscript: https://github.com/ThiefMaster/SO-UserScripts/blob/master/StackOverflow_DeleteComments.user.js

Comment: An important point: we (moderators) do go look at context when context might matter at all. We don't need to do that for obviously obscene or spammy comments that could not possibly be useful. That's why having an on-page mechanism to delete comments would be helpful. (I didn't want to edit this in to hijack the question, but I mentioned this in my [recent duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283873/238426) and want to make sure people see it in this discussion as well.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will be available in the next build. Moderators have the ability to edit and delete comments from each users comments history available the mod tools.

Thanks to [Marc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) for getting this done so quickly this week!

Comment: Awesome; thank you, and thanks, Marc!

Answer (score 2):

ThiefMaster created a userscript to add deletion from the comments list, which he linked in a comment:

> For deletion there's this userscript: [github.com/ThiefMaster/SO-UserScripts/blob/master/…](https://github.com/ThiefMaster/SO-UserScripts/blob/master/StackOverflow_DeleteComments.user.js) – [ThiefMaster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147015/thiefmaster) [Mar 12 '14 at 9:41](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145991/allow-moderators-to-edit-delete-comments-directly-from-the-per-user-comment-mode#comment735241_145991)

Based on that userscript, I've created a version that improves on the existing workflow, and adds in-page editing capabilities. It's not quite the same as a built-in feature, but it's a decent workaround.

Direct install [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArtOfCode-/Userscripts/master/stackexchange/mod/comment_history_delete.user.js), for those using Grease/Tampermonkey, and the source is [here](https://github.com/ArtOfCode-/Userscripts/blob/master/stackexchange/mod/comment_history_delete.user.js).

Comment: Nice! I'd still like to see this built-in, but the userscript is a good workaround for the moment.