# Allow moderators to edit/delete comments directly from a user's comment list

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, moderator-tools, moderation

Moderators currently have access to a nifty list of all a user's comments (500 at a time), which [now includes a summary of flags on those comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280681/238426). Unfortunately, we still have to visit the post where the comment was made before we can do anything about those comments, even if there is a pending flag.

The two-step process makes sense when we're trying to figure out if, say, a comment is obsolete; we need the context. It doesn't make sense if, for example, we're just trying to delete the user's 60 comments that all say something like, "You people suck," or "This isn't a homework site. Go RTFM." It's pretty safe to nuke those on sight. After all, moderators are, by definition, trusted users. We should trust them to be able to figure out when to do more investigation and when to nuke from orbit.

**I propose fixing this by giving ♦︎ moderators the ability to edit or delete comments directly from the last-500-comments list.** As far as I can tell, this was last [proposed back in 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145991/238426), but never got any traction. I think it's time.

Comment: There's a userscript that lets you delete from comment history, which could happily be modified to allow for editing too. I'll see if I can get to doing that.

Comment: @ArtOfCode That would be helpful, for sure. Thanks. I saw a mention of that on the 2012 post, but I wasn't sure of its status. In any case, this seems like it should probably be baked-in. I *already* have over a dozen userscripts running on SO/SE sites...

Comment: @EdCottrell: status of the script: I use it and it works. Adding in editing would be awesome, ArtOfCode, I'd use it.

Comment: Pretty sure this is just a duplicate of the other request, right?  I'm not sure I see much of a difference.

Comment: @bluefeet I am asking for the same thing, yes, though that 2012 post is slightly inaccurate now (we have a few more on-page abilities) and never got an answer.

Comment: @EdCottrell Still makes it a dup, maybe put a bounty on the other one to draw some attention to it. :)

Comment: @bluefeet Done. :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters and Ed: I've taken the old script and added editing to it - I'll post it in an answer to the dupe.

Comment: Nice job, @ArtOfCode.